# Customized association handling in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to manually and conditionally handle creating associations between models. I have an application with a tagging feature, such that there are three models: a Tag, a taggable Asset, and a joining model AssetTag. I want Assets to handle being tagged with pre-existing Tags as well as new Tags that the user can specify in the Asset's "tags" attribute when creating/updating an Asset. I'm guessing that the incoming JSON will look something like this:

```
{
  "item_number": "ITEM_NUMBER",
  "name": "Sample Asset",
  "description": "A sample asset.",
  "type": "print",
  "url": "http://www.example.com",
  "tags": [
    "sample asset",
    "arbitrary tag"
  ]
}
```

I assume that my approach should be to first iterate through each entry in "tags", and either load the Tag if one has the same `name` in the database or create a new one if it does not. Then, for each Tag found, create an AssetTag linking the Asset and Tag. Then, create or update the Asset.

What I'm confused on is how to manually handle the new/updated Asset attributes, and where that code would live. My first guess is that the code would go under `changeset` in `asset.ex`:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> load_or_create_tags
  |> create_asset_tags
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
end

def load_or_create_tags(model) do
 # do stuff here
end

def create_asset_tags(model) do
 # do stuff here
end
```

but then I'd have to reference Tag and AssetTag in the Asset module, and that feels a bit dirty. I also don't like the idea of altering the changeset function directly.

I'm also not sure how this works in general. I know that I can't just add models to the database in the middle of a changeset or something, so I assume I'd have to put everything off until right before the `insert` statement. This is also a process that involves coordinating three different models (Asset, Tag, AssetTag), and I don't think code like that belongs on a single model, but I don't know where else it would go.

Does my approach make sense? How should I handle this manually, and where do I put my code? I'm used to Rails, if it helps explain my thought process.